# change background of div  javascript class by css

Tags: javascript, css

i have problem this is javascript function its dont show the image in background.

```
document.getElementById(showtag).className='loadings';
```

and this is class property in **css** i think the problem is in url path.loading.gif is in images folder.

```
.loadings
{
  height:50px;
  padding-left:15em;
  background-image:url('images/loading.gif');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: visual basic or eclipse or what.. and you use grails or asp.net or what

Comment: php and ajax .it will not load the image.the problem in path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have a directory structure like:

```
/css/style.css
/images/loading.gif
```

so your CSS is pointing to

```
/css/images/style.css
```

If so, add a `/` to the front of the URL.

Comment: u mean like this
**url('/images/loading.gif')**

Comment: @sadi: Yes. *(What else could he mean?)*

Comment: @T.J i have directory structure 
style/main.css
and 
**url('/images/loading.gif')** not working

Comment: @sadi: I think David's basic point is that relative URLs in CSS stylesheets are [relative to the *style sheet*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri), not to the document containing it. So you need to think in terms of what the relative path to the image would be from the style sheet. Putting the `/` at the beginning (**not** my favored solution) at least lets you think relative to the server rather than relative to the style sheet. But if you can use a true relative path (like `../images/loading.gif` or similar, **if** that's where the image is), that would be more portable.

Comment: @sadi: *"i have directory structure style/main.css and url('/images/loading.gif') not working"* Well, is the `loading.gif` at `http://yourservername/images/loading.gif`? If not, that's your problem. Use tools to find out what things look like at runtime, as I said in point #1 in my answer, there's no excuse in 2011 for not using tools to inspect what's happening client-side properly. More: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the right path for the gif.

Now let's say your css loads from the path `/style`, and the image you look for is stored in the path `/img/backgroundimages`, then the background-image url could be `url(../img/backgroundimages/loading.gif)` *or* `url(/img/backgroundimages/loading.gif)`. In other words, use a relative path originating from the path your css-file is stored, *or* use the absolute path from the server root (prefixing the url with `/`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable `showtag` contains the `id` of an element that *already* exists on the page, your code should work.

So things to look at:

1. Does `showtag` have the correct value? (Check it by single-stepping the code in a debugger; in 2011, there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using debuggers for client-side code.)
2. Does the element exist when the code runs? Or is it added later? If it's added later, you will want to schedule your code to run later (by putting your `script` element at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` element, or by using `window.onload` or whatever "loaded" or "ready" event is provided by your library, if you're using one).
3. What happens if you manually add a `div` with that class to the page? Do the styles from the class get applied correctly? If not, you know you have a CSS/HTML problem, not a JavaScript problem. The developer tools in most browsers (see point 1 above) will help you figure out what the CSS problem is as well — for instance, by showing you that the image request is a 404 if the path to the image is incorrect.